# JBoss service is shutdown when windows is updated

Tags: java, windows, service, jboss, jboss7.x

I have installed Jboss as a service on my windows machine.It is running fine but When I updated my windows JBoss service is get shutdown.

***My shutdown.log file***

```
Shutting down JBoss Application Server 6.1.0 [2014-01-10 21:28:30]
JAVA_HOME is not set. Unexpected results may occur.
Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message.
org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.cli:main
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:224)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:341)
Shutdown JBoss Application Server 6.1.0 service [2014-01-10 21:28:31]
```

After reading I have set ***-Xrs*** option in `standalone.conf.bat` file as

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xrs"
```

Is this a right approach or there is any other option so that JBoss service is not get shutdown when I update Windows.

***EDIT***

I am using my own jre which is bundled with JBoss and in `standalone.bat` file I have already set my `JAVA_HOME` so JBoss was running fine and it was using my own `JAVA_HOME` which I have set in `standalone.bat` file but when I update my windows JBoss service is getting shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using JBoss Native to run the service, you can change **`service.bat`** to set JAVA_HOME.

As the Following  :

```
%JAVA_HOME% = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_15
```

so that when ever you update the windows it will be independent based on your service.bat

Hope this will helps you

Answer (score 0):

Your JAVA_HOME variable is not declared.

Set this environmental variable JAVA_HOME
[image]